# How to select dates in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to writing a query which can return a result if date time column(fromdate) is either null or fromdate is before a current date. Here is my query:

```
select * from patients where from date =null OR from date  <= cast(cast(getdate() as date)as datetime)
```

but this query returning empty result. Can someone confirm me both checking null OR before currentDate check in query is valid or not ?

---------Apply filter on more than 1 column:-----------

```
SELECT *
FROM patients
WHERE(fromDate = NULL
      OR t1.fromDate <= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
     AND (t1.toDate = NULL
          OR t1.toDate >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()));
```

I have a null column in todate in table but apply like this give me empty result

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you

```
SELECT *
FROM patients
WHERE fromdate IS NULL
      OR fromdate <= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

Comment: fromdate =null is wrong , fromdate  IS NULL is right

Comment: Ahhh Yes i need to use IS instead if = Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would do:

```
select p.*
from patients p
where p.fromdate is null or p.fromdate <= cast(getdate() as date);
```

Notes:

- According to your question `fromdate` does not have a space in it.
- The correct comparison for `NULL` is `IS NULL`, not `= NULL`.
- There is no need to cast a `date` back to a `datetime` for the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from patients where [fromdate] is null OR [fromdate]  <= cast(getdate() as datetime)
```